# How do I see the commands that are run by GNU make?

Tags: gnu-make, nvidia

I'm trying to debug a complex Makefile. How do you get GNU make to print all the commands it runs? I couldn't find the answer in the `man` page (using the -d flag doesn't seem to print it).

(This isn't necessary information to answer my question, but in case you're wondering: I'm having trouble compiling a project built on NVIDIA's CUDA library. I can compile it myself, but using their Makefile results in a nasty compiler error. I'd like to use their provided Makefile for easier packaging, and inclusion of other packages that they link in already.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`-n` triggers a "dry run"](http://www.sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_9.html#SEC88) in which no command is executed, though the commands which would execute are printed.

If your Makefile is recursive, though, this won't help much.

Comment: IIRC, `-n` works just fine with recursive `Makefiles` if they use `$(MAKE)`.

Comment: doh.  Exactly what I was looking for -- I need to get my eyes checked.  Much thanks for the speedy response.  (also, it seems to work fine with CUDA's nested Makefiles)