# Make recursive dry-run

Tags: makefile

I need to look at which commands are being used by make, but running command `make --dry-run` does not show the commands used by an internal `make -C /foo`.

Is there any way to make this work recursively?

Comment: @downvoter && coming-downvoters kindly specify reason. Or if the answer is so simple then let me know, I am not able to find solution for this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I see the commands that are run by GNU make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870538/how-do-i-see-the-commands-that-are-run-by-gnu-make)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To allow `-n` to work recursively, invoke make recursively with `$(MAKE)` instead of just `make`.

```
foo:
        $(MAKE) -C /foo
```